# MongoDb exclude null in aggregation $project

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-aggregation

I have a data collection in MongoDb with the shape:

```
[{ "_id": "1",
  "Sq1" : 5, 
  "Sq1comment" : "In general you aaaaaa.", 
  "Sq2" : 8, 
  "S2comment" : null, 
  "Sq3" : 5, 
  "Sq3comment" : "A person bbbbb."
 },
 { "_id": "2",
   "Sq1" : 4, 
   "Sq1comment" : "In general you cc.", 
   "Sq2" : 8, 
   "S2comment" : "A story ff", 
   "Sq3" : 5, 
   "Sq3comment" : null
 }
]
```

I would like to extract the 'comment' fields, but only reflect those which are not null in the result.

I can extract the fields (Sq1comment; Sq2comment, Sq3comment) one-by-one with a query

```
db.collection.find({ "Sq1comment": { $not: { $type: 10 } })
```

for which the output is:

```
[{ "_id": "1",
  "Sq1comment" : "In general you aaaaaa.", 
  "Sq3comment" : "A person bbbbb."
 }]
```

or if I do an aggregation $project the 'comment' fields all the nulls are there:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$project: 
   { "Sq1comment": "$Sq1comment",
     "Sq2comment": "$Sq2comment",
     "Sq3comment": "$Sq3comment"
   } }])
```

for which the output is:

```
[{ "_id": "1",
  "Sq1comment" : "In general you aaaaaa.", 
  "S2comment" : null, 
  "Sq3comment" : "A person bbbbb."
 },
 { "_id": "2",
   "Sq1comment" : "In general you cc.", 
   "S2comment" : "A story ff", 
   "Sq3comment" : null
 }
]
```

I want a project the data to show all comment fields, but only the entries which are not null. Thus exclude the null fields is the aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `$unwind`, then `$group` to get the result you want.

Like this:

```
{
  $unwind:
    {
      path: <field path>,
      includeArrayIndex: <string>,
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: <boolean>
    }
}
```

`preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` will help exclude null ones.

More links to visit:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/